# Android Studio update not showing libs folder

Tags: android

I update Android Studio 0.9 and after update hide libs folder in project structure

[image]

But in real folders i see libs folder, and in gradle script compile libs have param

[image]

Comment: "problem" is the "Android" selected in the ComboBox above "app" ... it is something like "type of view" ... choose "Project" or something similar and you will see it again